# C++ dynamic arrays. Why does this one work?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I was looking at this algorithm, the second one: Dynamic Programming Solution

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-24-optimal-binary-search-tree/

It creates a dynamic array: int cost[n][n];

How does this work? I can run the code on GeeksForGeeks C++ emulator, but locally in Visual Studio I get the error "Expression must have a constant value".

What am I misunderstanding here? Doesn't C++ need to know the size of the array before compiling?

Comment: VLAs are non-standard c++, some compilers (such as GCC) have support for them but it shouldn't be relied on as it's not portable code.

Comment: The source calls it a C/C++ implementation which already makes me wonder about the correctness of any of the code. In C99 VLAs are supported by the standard AFAIK.

Comment: How `sizeof` works on such array?

Comment: The compiler needs to know the size of all but the last dimension when declared this way. Since n isn't known at compile time, it fails this condition. A better solution might be to use new or vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is not standard.

```
type name[runtime_size]
```

Is what is called a variable length array.  This is not standard in C++ and will only compile in compilers that have an extension for this like g++ or clang.  The reason this extension exists is it is valid in C99.

You are completely correct that the size of the array must be known at compile time.  If you need an array and the size will not be know until run time I suggest you use a `std::vector` or a `std::unique_ptr<type[]>`.

Comment: Another option would be to use new.

Comment: @JacobMcCarthy, yes but only after `vector` and `array` have been investigated and found wanting. They are not found wanting very often.